# DataBindingMergeDependencyArtifact is slowing build

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

The build time of our application is slowly getting out of hand and it slowing down our process. Using the new build analyzer included with Android we think we found the problematic task. DataBindingMergeDependencyArtifact take often more than 50% of the build time when deploying on the phone. For some reason it is quicker when using "build" then when using "assemble".
Also note that our application have several module.

```
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding = false
    viewBinding = true
    buildConfig = true
}
```

[Example of build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tt8m.png)

Comment: Hi there,
Did you find a solution to this problem ? 

I am facing the same issue

Comment: The source is actually the snapshot. Removing the snapshot solve it. You can play with the configuration 'cacheChangingModulesFor'. Otherwise try to make smaller module to avoid blocking parallel build.

We still have the issue right now.